# Adding headers to WSRequest in WS client from Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, webservice-client

I have a service which requires authentication through headers. I have an existing java client which generates the values for me. I am trying to apply the headers to a ws request using a WSRequestHeaderFilter.

The code seems to run fine when I breakpoint and I can see the headers are applied. But in my Test Server (using the play SIRD router) the headers to not seem to be applied?

How can I make my required headers appear in the request using a filter or such method?

See the code below:

Filter:

```
class AuthenticatingFilter @Inject() (authHeaderGenerator: AuthHeaderGenerator) extends WSRequestFilter  {
      def apply(executor: WSRequestExecutor): WSRequestExecutor = {
        new WSRequestExecutor {
          override def execute(request: WSRequest): Future[WSResponse] = {
            val headers = authHeaderGenerator.generateRequestHeaders(request.method, request.uri.toString, null).asScala.toList
            executor.execute(request.withHeaders(headers:_*))
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Usage in client:

```
//code omitted for brevity
def getStuff() = ws.url(s"${baseUrl}/authenticatedEndpoint").withRequestFilter(filter).get()
```

Test:

```
 // code omitted for brevity

 Server.withRouter() {
        case GET(p"/authenticatedEndpoint") => Action {
          request =>

            request.headers.get(authHeader) match {
              case Some(authHeaderValue) => Results.Ok(expectedResult)
              case _ => Results.Forbidden
            }
        }
      } {
        implicit port =>
          implicit val materializer = Play.current.materializer

          WsTestClient.withClient {
            client =>
              val authenticatedClient: AuthenticatedClient = new AuthenticatedClient(client,filter)
              val result: String = Await.result(authenticatedClient.getStuff(), Duration.Inf)
              result must beEqualTo(expectedResult)
          }

      }
    }
```

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out this was a bug in play. I patched this and the change was merged into the master branch (https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/6077) so if you are having similar problems this should be fixed by upgrading to play 2.5.3 (when available)